# Where is the method_missing defined in ruby

Tags: ruby

I use ruby-1.9.3.

When the `method_missing method` came, I try to find out where this method was defined.
I take a look at Ruby Doc, and find that the method was defined in `BasicObject`, 
But when I use `BasicObject.methods.grep /^method/` in irb, It gave me a result array without any `method_missing` method, Then, I try `Kernel.methods.grep /^method/`, and still no `method_missing` method there.

Can you Help me? Where can I find this method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`Method#owner`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Method.html#method-i-owner) to know which method is defined in which class.

```
method(:method_missing).owner # => BasicObject
```

Answer (score 7):

It's a private method:
Try:

```
BasicObject.private_methods.grep /missing/
```

Comment: @stevenGe In that case, you need to accept the answer as correct. This is the correct policy on SOW.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see the source, you'll have to dig around in C code (for MRI) e.g. with `gem install pry pry-doc` you can do

```
~$ pry
[1] pry(main)> show-source method_missing

From: vm_eval.c (C Method):
Owner: BasicObject
Visibility: private
Number of lines: 7

static VALUE
rb_method_missing(int argc, const VALUE *argv, VALUE obj)
{
    rb_thread_t *th = GET_THREAD();
    raise_method_missing(th, argc, argv, obj, th->method_missing_reason);
    UNREACHABLE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else is reading some old materials and get confused, this method apparently used to belong to Kernel module until v1.8.7.330. Now, as mentioned, it's been moved to BasicObject.

http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/method_missing